# How does malware such as Stuxnet and Flamer propagate through USB memory sticks?

Tags: known-vulnerabilities, virus, zero-day

The best explanation I found is from [this article](http://www.matrixgp.com/?page_id=760) but it still is unclear to me. Apparently a new vulnerability has been found involving .lnk files where when a folder on the memory stick containing the .lnk file is viewed any file on the stick can be run? How does this work and is this a zero day vulnerability?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are almost correct - .lnk files should be a shortcut to a file, but here the .lnk itself is crafted to effectively autorun an exploit rather than calculate the shortcut to the intended file.

The [Microsoft Security Advisory](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/advisory/2286198) from 2010 gives more information along with the fix in [MS10-046](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/MS10-046) so this is not a zero day.